# WordPress rewrite post url to keep page url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks

I was wondering if it's possible to rewrite the url of a post to keep the current url as permalink and add the post name at the end of current url. I ask this because I've created a custom WP_Query and integrated that in a page.

So I want the url to be like `http://sitename.me/pagename` (here is the custom query) and the post link would look like `http://sitename.me/pagename/postname` instead of `sitename.me/category/postname`.

Do you have any suggestions how can this be achieved?

Thanks,
Ciprian

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to fetch someone with out knowing their identity!

You will have to send the `postname` some way or the other. May be through `Input Type=Hidden` and fetch it from the query-string.

Comment: Or, would be easier with cookies?

Comment: @CiprianTepesBobescu
Ya, that would ease things. Even then `mod_rewrite` cannot be of help. I suggest you to handle the redirection through the programming language you are using.